# Show div when click on its ::before element with only CSS?

Tags: css

I wish to hide div contents and show only its `::before` pseudo-element. Click on `::before` element should show the `<div>` contents.
As I read I cannot use `div::before:hover`, selector.
I can do this by adding another element to the page like tag A. But no, I need a solution where I cannot add any other element, only pseudo-elements and only CSS (no-js, no-HTML).

I tried here: [jsfiddle Show on click on ::before](https://jsfiddle.net/youni/o354hma6/20/)

```css
/* show hide quoted email text */
div.gmail_quote {
    background: pink;
}

div.gmail_quote:before {
    font-size: 1em !important;
    visibility: visible;
    display: block;
    content: 'show';
    display: block;
    padding: 5px;
    background: #E9A;
}

div.gmail_quote>* {
    font-size: 2px;
}

div.gmail_quote:hover>* {
    font-size: 1em;
    background: magenta;
}

div.gmail_quote::before:active+div.gmail_quote {
    background: white;
}

.shower:focus+div.gmail_quote {
    background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <a class=shower href=#>permanent block shower on click</a>
    <div class="gmail_quote">
        <p>Hello<br>
            Would you be so kind to show an example?<br>
            Is it still possible to get a solution?
            How to show this block not on hover on it but on click on its ::before?
            <br><br>
            Block content.
            <p>
    </div>

    <br><br><br><br>
    I need to show block on click on its ::before element
</body>
</html>
```

There click on A element changes the div background and works fine. But in my task I cannot add any HTML code, I should use only CSS for that div.gmail_quote.

Could you, please, advise?

Comment: Use `:active` instead of `:hover`. Working example : https://jsfiddle.net/w69sr87m/

Comment: thank you. i need to click and move mouse from it and it should rest visible